# Difference between gradle upload and gradle publish

Tags: gradle

I am testing pushing my artifacts to a Nexus maven repository. I am using `gradle` to do so.

What is the difference between `gradle upload` and `gradle publish`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently gradle provides two publishing mechanisms. Original - shipped with java plugin - is described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/artifact_management.html) and is based on a task of type [`Upload`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Upload.html). This mechanism is going to be replaced by the - currently incubating - second mechanism that is separated from java plugin and also splitted into maven and ivy. This new mechanism is described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

Answer (score 3):

Also have a look at "[Upgrading your build from Gradle 6.x to the latest](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#changes_7.0)": "*Removal of the `uploadArchives` task: The `uploadArchives` task was used in combination with the legacy Ivy or Maven publishing mechanisms. It has been removed in Gradle 7. You should migrate to the `maven-publish` or `ivy-publish` plugin instead*."